# Mysql WHERE clause equal all elements

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm doing a query throughout a **form** where the type of element is selected in a **select**.

My query is something like:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE element = $selection.
```

now, one of the option in the selection is show all. How can I do a query like:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE element = ALL?
```

I know I could validate it and use **two** different queries for each case,

element selected:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE element = $selection
```

and if `$selection == 'all'` then use:

```
SELECT * from table
```

but this is just an example and in my case I would have to do **too many queries**, which I could do but I want to check beforehand if I can use only **ONE** query for both cases.

this is my code:

```
function displayElements($sec,$ele,$from,$to){ // sec and ele could be set to 'ALL'
    mysql_connect("#", "#", "#") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("#") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");    
    //queries
    if($ele == 'Box'){
        $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE seccion = '$sec' AND elemento LIKE '%Box:%' AND fecha BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY fecha ASC");
    }
    else{
        $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elementos WHERE seccion = '$sec' AND elemento = '$ele' AND fecha BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY fecha ASC");
    }

    if (!$resultado) {
        echo "No se pudo ejecutar con exito la consulta ($sql) en la BD: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) == 0) {
        echo "nada para mostrar.";
    exit;
    }..blablabla
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is the input table and how does the desired result-table looks like (not all 20.000 datas, but an example ;) )

Comment: just leave the `where`? or use `where element in ('...','...'), if the statement is automatically generated

Answer (score 1):

Why use two queries (pseudo code below may help) ?

```
q = "select * from table";
q += (a == "ALL") ? "" : " where element in...";
```

Comment: Exactly.  Why even have a `WHERE` if you want all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just all Elements of a table do `SELECT * from table`

without any `WHERE ...`

Comment: I know, but I want to have only one query for both cases, when specific element is selected and all element selected

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use two different queries in your case. But in a case when there are, say, 5 selection boxes, each of which may contain a specific string, or "nothing selected", i start with a "syntax sugar" statement like

```
select * from table where 1=1
```

Then, for each selection box, i add a string like

```
and columnX = 'valuex'
```

to the statement. The 1=1 will get thrown away by the optimizer anyway, and this saves me some hassle with checking if i have to use "where" or "and" when adding a constraint.

WARNING: using this in a real life environment opens your code to SQL inhjection. What you really should do, unless you're learning, is add

```
and columnX = ?
```

to the query string, append valuex to an array, then use that array to bind the variables when you start the select.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass `element` **field** itself to your query then

`WHEN element = element`

would not filter out anything except `NULL`s, but **any** equality check will filter out NULLs anyway, since *NULL is not equal to NULL*.

Comment: that works great when using like:
WHEN element = $element (and having $element='element')
BUT the query is WHEN element = '$element' (the quotes makes it an invalid solution, and when removing the quotes the normal query results in error)

Comment: If you were using `LIKE` than you could've just used a wild-card to get all.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a SELECT into your where:

```
select * from seldat,mydat where element=(
   select 
      case 
         when query_element='ALL' then element
        else query_element
      end

   )
```

[SQL Fiddle for use without 'like'](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d96b33/3)

**EDIT for academic use only**

```
    create table mydat (
      field1 varchar(128),
      element varchar(128)
    );

    create table seldat (
       query_element varchar(128)
      );

    insert into mydat values 
      ('field A', 'basic element'),
      ('field B', 'cpp element'),
      ('filed C', 'cpp file'), 
      (null,null)
    ;


    insert into seldat values 
      ('ALL'), 
      ('basic element'), 
      ('cpp%'), 
      ('cpp element'),
      ('cpp file')
```

then the following SQL works:

```
    select * from seldat,mydat where element in (
      select 
         case 
           when query_element='ALL' then element
           else query_element
          end
       union
       select element from  mydat 
           where element like query_element
    )
```

[Full featured variant with like](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8d6c/1)